# Updating div content after form submit without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

alright, I have a popup which displays some notes added about a customer. The content (notes) are shown via ajax (getting data via ajax). I also have a `add new` button to add a new note. The note is added with ajax as well. Now, the question arises, after the note is added into the database.

How do I refresh the `div` which is displaying the notes?

I have read multiple questions but couldn't get an answer.

My Code to get data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cid = $('#cid').val();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php?requestid=1&cid="+cid,             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#notes").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**DIV**

```
<div id="notes">
</div>
```

My code to submit the form (adding new note).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var note = $("#note").val();
        var cid = $("#cid").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php?requestid=2",
            data: { note: note, cid: cid }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert(msg);
            $("#make_new_note").hide();
            $("#add").show();
            $("#cancel").hide();
            //$("#notes").load();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried `load`, but it doesn't work.

Please guide me in the correct direction.

Comment: Try  `$("#notes").append(msg);`

Comment: How would that help? Contents of `msg` are just true or false.

Comment: lol, how would we know that looking at your code? `ajax.php` could return anything you want it to. See my answer below

Comment: Please post your PHP code as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to call the ajax and get the data from `ajax.php` then just call the function whenever you need to update the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create a function to call the ajax and get the response
  function getResponse() {
    var cid = $('#cid').val();
    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php?requestid=1&cid=" + cid,
      dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
      success: function(response) {
        $("#notes").html(response);
        //alert(response);
      }

    });
  }
  getResponse(); // call the function on load


  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var note = $("#note").val();
    var cid = $("#cid").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php?requestid=2",
      data: {
        note: note,
        cid: cid
      }
    }).done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
      $("#make_new_note").hide();
      $("#add").show();
      $("#cancel").hide();}
      getResponse(); // call the function to reload the div

    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: None of the solutions worked.
First one would never work because I written `true` or `false` in `msg`.

Comment: Again, we would have no way of knowing what `msg` returned, sorry, I assumed you were returning the message/note. As for the other method not working. The only way that would be possible is if you are not actually saving your changes to your database. Can we see the code in `ajax.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a URL to jQuery load() function to tell where you get the content.
So to load the note you could try this:

```
$("#notes").load("ajax.php?requestid=1&cid="+cid);
```