# How to replacing div content with other content after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to know how i can replace an div with data with new data after an onchange function.

Seeing some of the answers i decided to change my post to make it more clear of what i want to do.

i have an div that has data comming from the database.
inside that div there is also an select so an user can change the row

now what i want is that if an user choose an color it will then call ajax.php to make the change to the database and then it must return new value.

so

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><select><option value="1">red</option><option value="2">Blue</option></select><td>
    <td>Rest of the data from the database</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now when the user has changed the color
the result now should be

```
<div>
<table>
<tr bgcolor="red"> <-- this is new data
    <td><select><option value="1">red</option><option value="2">Blue</option></select><td>
    <td>Rest of the data from the database</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

See example
[image]

As you can see the first row is where users can change the color.

Comment: so what problem you are facing?And don't mix java-script/jQuery syntax's with each-other.Use either-one purely.

Comment: use jquery on change event. read documentation https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: where is #container in your html ?

Comment: Where is the #container element? Doesn't it have to be there before you set content?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896958/updating-div-content-after-form-submit-without-page-reload

Comment: You completely changed your question and now it need lot of work to do.

Comment: Yes i was aware of that. My bad i will its seems i have messed things up quite an bit. I will change it. never ask questions when you also have kids arround you.

Answer (score 0):

I think as i understand your Question , your code should be seems like below .

```
    <script>

    function chk(obj)
    {
        var name=$(obj).val();
        var dataString='name='+ name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function( returnedData ) {
                $( '#container' ).html( returnedData );
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>


<div class="data" >

    here is some data that comes from mysql database.

    <form method="post" action="" id="formSearch">  

        <select name="color" class="test" id="name" onchange="chk(this);">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1" style="background-color: #ff0000"></option>
            <option value="2" style="background-color: #3000ff"></option>
            <option value="3" style="background-color: #36ff00"></option>
            <option value="4" style="background-color: #e400ff"></option>
            <option value="5" style="background-color: #fff000"></option>
        </select>

    </form>

    <div id="container">

    </div>

</div>
```